# What is the best practice for using `secrets` in Symfony 6?

Tags: symfony, environment-variables, symfony6

In Symfony 6,

`bin/console secrets:set MY_VAR`

seems super handy, especially to create environment specific variables - but if you have to upload the generated private decryption key to the server anyway, and the variable values are easily accessible via

`bin/console secrets:list --reveal`

, what are the advantages of using secrets via the cli vs simply defining `MY_VAR` in an environment-specific `.env` file, uploaded to the server and out of vcs?

Comment: This is something I think every dev has thought of. Eventually software need the raw data (like a password). Secrets are just a way of encrypting the raw data away, so that nobody can read it directly. Not necessarily if somebody had broken into your application, but also for employees or (remote) CI/CD tools. They don't need the raw data.
If your infrastructure uses some vault mechanism, this also comes in handy because your secrets can be safely pulled from a vault, where nobody really needs access to secrets. 
While the password remains the same, the secret can be rotated.

Comment: fwiw @Leroy I ended up using the Symfony secrets, but overriding the command that shows the secrets in plain text after checking the host - if the host was one of our actual servers (and not a docker container) the secrets are hidden, if it's a docker container (presumably a dev env) then the secrets are visible - not foolproof, but not as simple as getting server access and then running secrets:show either